# Object is possibly undefined during ternary operator

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to pull my userid from my state

My object is possibly undefined and I want to irradicate this error, so I use a ternary operator. However I still get the same error (this.store.getState().account is possibly undefined). Why?

```
var myUser = this.store.getState().account.me.id ? this.store.getState().account.me.id : 0
```

Context (but also really just cognitive noise) - I use this in componentDidMount to get the userID that is populated from a redux state. me is an optional state, but account is not (these are stored in redux)

Comment: What is this used in? Can you give a larger code sample and explain the process a little?

Comment: `this.store.getState().account && this.store.getState().account.me && this.store.getState().account.me.id` - (removed other stuff after re-reading question)

Comment: This sounds like a warning from your IDE, not an actual error that occurs when you run the program.

Comment: Barmar - is a warning but I have been told to eradicate such from my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to access a property of something that's undefined, an error will be thrown; if `.account` property is undefined, then `this.store.getState().account.me.id ?` will throw. (the ternary won't resolve to `0`, the script will fail completely)

Also, you're calling `getState()` twice, when you only need to call it once. Try something like this instead:

```
const account = this.store.getState().account;
const myUser = account ? account.me.id : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer will work but again you may get same error thrown if account.me returns undefined. In these cases of accessing nested properties I prefer the try, catch as it can catch cannot access property of undefined at any level

```js
var myUser;
try {
   myUser = this.store.getState().account.me.id;
} catch(err) {
   myUser = 0;
}
console.log(myUser);
```